# The one with a red door. / The one with the red door

Tags: articles

Is it possible that "a" or "the" can be used in these examples? If it's possible, so "a" article means that there are some other red doors near here? Or does it mean something else?

> ‘That’s a nice house.’ ‘Which one?’ ‘The one **with a red door**.’
>
> ‘That’s a nice house.’ ‘Which one?’ ‘The one **with the red door**.’

Comment: This is a good question.  In this context, I would always say "with **the** red door", but I wouldn't exactly say it was *wrong* to say "with **a** red door".  I think I would use **the** because there's a kind of implied "that we can see right now" that makes it specific.

Comment: @stangdon, As I understand your thought, you also would use "the" (not "a") in the following case: Which doll would you like to have, darling? The one in **the** violet dress. But I suppose this example is more obvious than in the post, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, in the example of the doll, I would definitely say "in **the** violet dress."  To me, that definitely implies there is one and only one doll that has a violet dress, and **a** sounds wrong...but why that is different from the question about houses, I am not sure.

Comment: What @stangdon said. I might be more likely to use ***a*** rather than ***the*** in the cited context if *at time of speaking*, the relevant house & door weren't directly visible to both conversants. Correspondingly, I'd be *much* more likely to use ***the*** if I was actually *pointing* at the referent while speaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct. "The one with **the** red door happens to be more natural.

The difference is subtle.

> The one with **a** red door

means "*There's only one house with a red door that we can see, and that's the house I'm talking about.*"

> The one with **the** red door

means "*There's only one red door that we can see, and I'm talking about the house that has that door*".

Functionally, they're identical.

Comment: If there are two houses with light red door and dark red door there, I could say only "The one with the light red door." Right? Or also "a" article is possible?

Comment: It's the same situation. Both are correct, and using "the" is more natural. I don't need to know the colours of any of the other doors, except to know that none of the others are red, or light red in your second example.

Answer (score 0):

There is almost no difference, but "the" red door shows more emphasis.

‘The one with a red door’ simply distinguishes that house from any others.

‘The one with the red door’ gives the difference more importance.

Comment: @Sergey No, if there's two, then you could say, "One of the two houses with a red door", which wouldn't be as helpful. When you say "the one", it means "the only one".

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin, Could you give some examples to provide your thoughts, please? I don't understand them clearly.

Comment: @Sergey If you first show where it became unclear… is the difference between distinction and emphasis difficult, or what?

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin, Unclear is your description. "It simply distinguishes" means that there is no other houses with red doors, right? What does it mean "gives the difference more importance" (in the second case)?

Comment: @Sergey That suggests you're not comfortable with my use of "emphasis." Is that right? Both mean there are no other houses with red doors and that isn't the point…